# Is making dua by raising hand after sunnah prayer valid?

Tags: salat, hadith, sunnah, dua, fatwa

Assalamualaikum.

I am seeing some hadith that making dua by raising hand after prayer is not valid. I found the following fatwa that is recommending making dua by raising hands after fard prayer.

> https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/84676/

I want to know that is making dua by raising hand after sunnah prayer and bitr prayer valid?

Please share some references regarding this.

Jazakallah.

Comment: As per the fatwa you quoted, it is valid. Though some may point out that there's no evidence the Prophet (ﷺ) did so.

Comment: jazakillah @Muslimahياربالعالمين sister